# What is the intuition behind win_type argument in rolling function of Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

The following code is from [Python DataScience Handbook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/03.11-Working-with-Time-Series.ipynb) (line 42)

```
daily.rolling(50, center=True,
              win_type='gaussian').sum(std=10).plot(style=[':', '--', '-']);
```

While I understand why we need rolling, I am unable to understand why are we using `win_type`.

Could you people please help in clearing this doubt? I've searched the Pandas documentation but unfortunately, they don't have the required explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am far from being an expert on the topic, but from my understanding the win_type argument is derived from signal processing concepts:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function

> In signal processing, a window function (also known as an apodization
>   function or tapering function[1]) is a mathematical function that is
>   zero-valued outside of some chosen interval. For instance, a function
>   that is constant inside the interval and zero elsewhere is called a
>   rectangular window, which describes the shape of its graphical
>   representation. When another function or waveform/data-sequence is
>   multiplied by a window function, the product is also zero-valued
>   outside the interval: all that is left is the part where they overlap,
>   the "view through the window".

Answer (score 1):

The 'win_type=' argument allows you to specify a windowing function that 'rolls' over your data.  In your example a Gaussian window is used with standard deviation width of 10 samples, and extends to 2.5 standard deviations on either side (total size of 50 samples).  If you don't specify 'win_type=' you'll get a rectangular window.

Note that if 'win_type=' is specified a 'window' subclass returned, otherwise a 'rolling' subclass is returned.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html